# Declaring variables within if/else block

Tags: java, class, declaration

I'm writing a program which creates a variable of an instance of a certain class if the first command line argument is "-1," and an instance of one of its child classes otherwise. The parent and child class share all the same methods and method names, but the child class overrides the parent for some of them. In other words the rest of the program after the declaration is exactly the same regardless of which class I use. Here's the declaration I have at the moment:

```
    if(args[0].compareTo("-1") == 0){
        BST Tree = new BST();
    }
    else{
        RBT Tree = new RBT();
    }
```

Which throws a "cannot be resolved" error when Tree is referenced later. Is there any solution to this problem without a bunch of redundant code? I could obviously just put the entire main function within these if/else blocks but I'd like to avoid that if there's a more concise solution.

Comment: How are BST and RBT related? Do they have common base class?

Comment: It seems like RBT extends BST.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you also declare variable `Tree` in the scope of the statements. Outside of those scopes, `Tree` can not be longer resolved.

You can declare `Tree` before the if statement:

```
BST Tree;

if(args[0].compareTo("-1") == 0){
    Tree = new BST();
} else {
    Tree = new RBT();
}

doSomethingWith(Tree); // Should work fine
```

Comment: In other words: the object is simply unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of the scope of the if-statement.

```
BST Tree;

if(args[0].compareTo("-1") == 0){
    Tree = new BST();
} else {
    Tree = new RBT();
}
```

This assumes that `RBT` extends `BST`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Tree` before the `if` block (so that it has visibility after the `if` block). Like,

```
BST Tree;
if(args[0].compareTo("-1") == 0){
    Tree = new BST();
}
else{
    Tree = new RBT();
}
```

**or** use a ternary like

```
BST Tree = (args[0].compareTo("-1") == 0) ? new BST() : new RBT();
```

Also, by convention Java variable names start with a lower case letter so I would prefer `tree` to `Tree` (which looks like a class name).